# how to add username and password field in commerce order

Tags: entities, commerce, users

I am new with Drupal and I am willing to learn more.

now, I am creating a project and I am using the drupal commerce.

In the check-out process, In default, for unregistered users, it has the `email field` and others field. I just want to add `username`, `password` and `password confirm` fields so that the anonymous user will register then he can pay for the item he cheked-out.

but the problem is I don't know how to add those fields.

I have also checked the `Checkout Rules (Create a new account for an anonymous order)`, I think the process of creating the user is done here, but I don't know how.

Does anyone can help me in my case?
any help will be appreciated...

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

This is currently being handled via the Rules module. The rule that is enabled by default creates the user via the "Create a new account for an anonymous order" rule. There is no way to insert a password in here but is up to the user to open the link in their email and set their password manually.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with below solution but I want to create a module for do this is future( If I will hav time :) )

first in my custom module add password field to checkout process

```
        function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form['#form_id'] == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
            global $user;
          if($user->uid==0)  {
          $form['account']['login']['pass'] = array(
          '#type' => 'password_confirm',
          '#title' => t('Password'),
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#size' => 30,
        );
          $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][]='_myfunction_user_register_incheckout_submit';
        }
        }
        }
```

then save password in session with

```
        function _myfunction_user_register_incheckout_submit($form,$form_state){
            $s_name='pass-'.$form_state['values']['account']['login']['mail'];
        //    $pass=user_hash_password($form_state['values']['account']['login']['pass']);
        // it's better hash it later , for more security    
            $pass=$form_state['values']['account']['login']['pass'];
            _ym_session($s_name,$pass);
        }


        function _ym_session($key, $value = NULL) {
          drupal_session_start();
          static $storage;
          if ($value) {
            $storage[$key] = $value ;
            $_SESSION['ym'][$key] = $value ;   // I use 'lists' in case some other module uses 'type' in $_SESSION
          }
          else if (empty($storage[$key]) && isset($_SESSION['ym'][$key])) {
            $storage[$key] = $_SESSION['ym'][$key]?$_SESSION['ym'][$key]:false;
          }
          return $storage[$key];
        }

        function _myfunction_user_register_incheckout($user_account){
            $s_name='pass-'.$user_account->mail;
            if(_ym_session($s_name)){
            $pass=_ym_session($s_name);
            user_save($user_account,array('pass'=>$pass));
        //    ym(user_load($user_account->uid),'message');
        //    ym(user_load($user_account->uid));
            }
        }
```

after it in `commerce_checkout_new_account` rules in `/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/commerce_checkout_new_account`
add a php action 
in **PHP CODE** section add

_myfunction_user_register_incheckout($account_created);

save it then  put it after `Fetch entity by property` and before 'LOOP' and save rule,

[image]

Then test  and enjoy it :D